# Querying large number of timestamps

Tags: php, database, datastore, nosql

I have a list of timestamps in a table (there can be millions) of every time an auto-save event occurs. I want to track the amount of time people spend on a page, so every time they type a word, I send a timestamp in addition to session id to a data store. The end timestamp - begin timestamp = amount of time spent on a page.

If I have a database of millions of such timestamps, what is the most efficient way to query for the amount of time spent a page?

I want to be able to do this on the user level and also on the aggregate (average amount of time user spends on page X).

I also want to do this real time. Be able to retrieve the amount of time user spends on page X in real time.

I was thinking of storing the data in memory because you might be getting many timestamps at once and that can overload the database as we would constantly have to update information. I was thinking of storing the data in memory as a key-value pair, and every X minutes, sending the data from memory to the data store (where I compute the time spent and store for each session id). So I would store the data in memory - key is the post id, value is an array of begin time and end time. Every X minutes, I send the data to the database; I would store the session id, page id, user id, and time spent (calculated by doing end_time - begin_time) in the database.

Is this a good solution to my problem? What am I missing?